# Tool for distributed compilation of C++/Qt software

Tags: windows, c++, compiler, qt

I am using C++/Qt/Qt Creator as IDE.

Is there a tool I can use to speed up compilation by distributing the task among my other computers (in my case Win 7 machines)?

Or is there even a service (on the internet, cloud) where I can compile my software?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is originally a linux/unix solution, it is highly usable with cygwin, too. There is a tool named [distcc](https://code.google.com/p/distcc/), which can distribute the most resource-intensive tasks between remote computers.

It is developed for gcc, but you can use that for other compilers as well with a little bit of scripting.

Answer (score 1):

By using a compilation cache like

- [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) for gcc
- [clcache](https://github.com/frerich/clcache) for Visual Studio

you can achieve great performance improvements with only little extra hardware requirements.